# How can I force anti-aliasing in GTA IV?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-iv

My GTA IV version is 1.0.7.0 and I am trying to enable anti-aliasing but I am unable to find a setting in the game to do this. The image preview below looks fine but if you click on the image and see its bigger size, you can see clear aliasing.

[image: Screenshot of GTA4]
<sub>Click image preview above to view higher-resolution, original-sized image.</sub>

My graphics card is a GTX560ti and I am trying to force anti-aliasing within the nVidia Control Panel but it's not taking effect.

How can I force anti-aliasing for Grand Theft Auto IV?

Comment: I don't know about NVIDIA, but there's a program that AMD/ATI uses called Catalyst Control Center that allows you to closely manage your graphics card. If NVIDIA has a program like that, you could use it to force AA.

Comment: @ks0830: At what settings are you running the game ?

Comment: Video Mode             : 1928 x 1080 (60Hz)
Texture Quality        : High
Reflection Resolution  : Very High
Water Quality          : Very High
Shadow Quality         : High
Night Shadows          : High
Texture Filter Quality : Anisotropic x16
View Distance          : 100
Detail Distance        : 100
Vehicle Density        : 100
Definition             : On
VSync                  : On

AND ALSO SMAA-ULTRA!!!!!!!

Comment: Did your game take a performance hit after applying AA ?

Comment: little. before, FPS was 34~55, avg was 45. now 29~54 avg is 38. little change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the driver software for both Nvidia and AMD/ATI can't force non-post processing AA in GTA IV due to how GTA IV's graphics engine was made (or rather, how it was ported to the PC from the console platform).

You can however, force post-processing AA on it, like FXAA (in Nvidia driver software settings), Morphological Anti-Aliasing (MLAA; in AMD/ATI driver software settings) or SMAA (which I believe provides better visual quality than the former post-processing AA methods). [SMAA](http://www.iryoku.com/smaa) can be used in GTA IV through **[injectSMAA](http://mrhaandi.blogspot.com/p/injectsmaa.html)**:

> Description:
>
> - adds "Subpixel Morphological Antialiasing" to an application
> - is based on "injectFXAA" (written by "some dude")
> - is supposed to work only with directx 9, directx 10, directx 11, x86 applications
> - may be incompatible with any other form of antialiasing
> - may be incompatible with overlays (Steam Overlay, MSI Afterburner, Fraps, ...)
>
> SMAA is a very efficient GPU-based MLAA implementation, capable of
>   handling subpixel features seamlessly, and featuring an advanced
>   pattern detection & handling mechanism.
>
> http://www.iryoku.com/smaa/

Screenshots (from http://mrhaandi.blogspot.com/p/injectsmaa.html):

<sup>Click image previews below to view higher-resolution, original-sized image.</sup>
No AA:
[image: No AA]

With SMAA:
[image: With SMAA]

Comment: HAHA Thats more like it! I really appreciate! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the nVidia Control Panel.

Under Manage 3D Settings, select the GTA IV profile or create a new one (for the GTA 4 executable). Then put Anti-aliasing FXAA "ON" and apply. You might also have to switch  Anti-aliasing control to "enhance the application setting" and select what level AA you want (ie 4x).

Comment: Not sure myself (as I do not use a nVidia card) but the accepted answer seems to indicate that this won't work - have you been able to test this?

Answer (score 1):

Forcing AA in Nvidia control panel doesn't work. The FXAA option should reduce aliasing and soften the image (textures get blurred) and isn't perfomance-heavy.

I've looked into this myself and the only methods of AA i discovered are.

1. FXAA in control panel
2. inject SMAA (as above)
3. SweetFX (google it, don't use with enb)

Answer (score 0):

I have used both a R9 270 and a GTX 970 with GTA IV, And Forcing AA with Enhance application settings x8 works great for me in either Nvidia Control Panel or Catalyst Control Center. It works really well. It also helps to select high quality texture. After that it looks almost as good as GTA V.